# How to flow type a React Component in apollo graphql

Tags: flowtype, react-apollo

I am trying to correctly type a react component with flow and apollo graphql. I keep getting a flow error message. I am using react-apollo 2.0.1 and flow 0.53.1

```
// @flow
/**
*
* CompanyName
*
*/

import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import type { OperationComponent, ChildProps } from 'react-apollo';

type Company = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
};

type Response = {
  company: Company,
};

type Props = {
  className: ?string,
};


class CompanyName extends React.Component<ChildProps<Props, Response>> {
  render() {
    return (
      <span className={this.props.className}>
        {!!this.props.data.company && this.props.data.company.name}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const query = gql`
  query {
    company {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const withCompanyName: OperationComponent<Response, Props> = graphql(query);

export default withCompanyName(CompanyName); // this line gives a flow error
```

I get an error on the last line of code saying that the type is incompatible. Everything else validates correctly.

The error message is: CompanyName (class type: CompanyName) This type is incompatible with StatelessComponent (union: type application of polymorphic type: type `StatelessComponent` | class type: type application of identifier `React$Component`)

I am able to get it to work properly if I change it to a stateless functional component, but I need to get this working for class components.

**Update:**
Here is my .flowconfig

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]

[options]
module.name_mapper='.*\(.gql\)' -> 'empty/object'
```

I am using the empty package to prevent gql imports from causing a flow error.

Comment: Can you add your `.flowconfig` file?